# Assign Future[Unit] to Unit

Tags: scala

Why does this compile

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> val f: Unit = Future.successful(())
f: Unit = ()
```

I expected the compiler to complain about the assignment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is called "Value Discarding". Citing the [scala specification (6.26.1)](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html):

> **Value Discarding**
>
> If e has some value type and the expected type is Unit, e is converted to the     expected type by embedding it in the term { e; () }.

In other words, any value, whatever its type, is implicitly converted to `Unit`, effectively discarding it.

It you want to be warned about such discarding (which can in some cases hide a bug), you can pass the `-Ywarn-value-discard` option to the compiler. You'll then have to explicitly return `()` every time you call a method only for its side effect, but that method does return a non-Unit value.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is fine since applying f will only execute the call

```
val f: Unit = Future.successful(())
```

and the return value will go into the nirvana.

Answer (score 2):

Basically this is the same as:

```
val f: Unit = {
    Future.successful(())
    ()
}
```

If the compiler don't find the Unit it expects in the last value of the method it will put it there.